# How do I create a dev and prod Firebase environment for iOS and android Capacitor/Ionic React app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, native, capacitor

With React Native, I just followed [this article](https://medium.com/@gregoire.frileux/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-dev-staging-prod-for-firebase-with-react-native-app-205c7c1a5e35) and it was as easy as that. I tried using the same method but it doesn't work. I'm wondering if there's a way I can do the same thing with Ionic React.

Tried using this article:
https://medium.com/@gregoire.frileux/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-dev-staging-prod-for-firebase-with-react-native-app-205c7c1a5e35

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.